# How do we register/transfer information?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, acceleration, equivalence-principle

I have in mind thought experiment where physicist is in elevator falling towards the Earth. Question would be if he is not allowed to look outside, how would he detect the presence of the planet? Let's not take in consideration tidal forces and assume he is taking local measurements during small time intervals. And whole experiment is in vacuum. Is there a way he can detect Earth under these conditions before he crashes into it?

The way I see things, there are only two conceptually different ways that our physicist can detect the Earth. Either by taking a peek outside of the elevator, or by crashing. These are two different ways we can transfer/register information from one point in space to another.

Interesting thing is that first method has to do with constant velocity, and second with acceleration. Let’s notice one more thing. First method of information transfer has its maximum, speed of light. Should the second one have its maximum? Should there be maximal possible acceleration/force in nature? Why would non-inertial reference frames be any special compared to inertial, and don’t have the property of maximal information transfer?

Comment: No, there is not. Otherwise GR would be false at basic level. By "title force" i guess you mean *tidal forces*.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE. Your title question does not seem to match the question in the body, and it's not clear what "title forces" are. Also, this seems to be a fairly standard application of the principle of relativity - what are your thoughts, and what *exactly* is unclear to you?

Comment: I guess, I didn't finished my original question that relates to title question.

Comment: I guess, I didn't finished my original question that relates to the title question. The way I see things, there are only two conceptually different ways that our physicist can detect the Earth. Either by taking a peek outside of the elevator, or by crashing. I was wondering if that is true, in the first place, and than, does that apply to our everyday lives. Are all the information that we receive during the day received by these two methods. Interesting thing is that first method has to do with constant velocity, and second with acceleration.

Comment: Let’s notice one more thing. First method of information transfer has its maximum, speed of light. Should the second one have its maximum? Should there be maximal possible acceleration/force in nature? Why would inertial reference frames be any special compared to non-inertial, and don’t have the property of maximal information transfer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "property of maximal information transfer". Information *requires* a force of some sort to be transferred.  In order to 'detect' the earth, all the physicist needs is light reflected from earth, or a drag measurement (drag increases with density). If somehow the elevator is being *actively* chaperoned toward the earth at rate that precisely cancels drag and if the elevator was built *perfectly* reflective, then the mysterious elevator might actually be strong enough to pass through the earth. Either way, the physicist is at liberty to sing o fortuna non-ironically.

Comment: By “maximal information transfer” I mean the capability of system to transfer information as fast as it can. For non-inertial systems that would be speed of light, for inertial that would be maximal acceleration. Forgot to mention, experiment is in vacuum so there is no drag. For the rest, I’m not sure what are you talking about. Elevator doesn’t need to be perfectly reflective, there’s nothing mysterious about the elevator, physicist doesn’t have to sing… Please, be polite.

Answer (score 0):

In first approximation, he can't.

If he has enough accurate instruments, he can detect the tidal force: the side of the lift to Earth is attracted a little bit more as the adverse. Thus the free falling lift feels a net force trying to tear it.

Around neutron stars or black holes, this tidal force can be enough strong to destruct the lift.

Comment: Agree, but as I said he is only allowed to do measurements locally during short periods of time. So, no tidal forces.

Comment: @PeraMitic Then I vote for Moretti. :-)

Comment: Yep, I agree with Moretti.